# How do you pass multiple scope parameters through a Facebook PHP SDK to execute queries that require permissions?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

I have a current 3-page web site/app to pull/display data from Facebook using my PHP SDK code, I'm getting the error:

> The redirect_uri URL must be absolute

This is because of this code below:

```
$params = array(
       'scope' => 'ads_management',
       'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/login-callback.php',
    );
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Before changing it to this, I didn't have this ^ at all, and just this line instead:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://example.com/login-callback.php');
```

If I were to query posts and stuff that didn't require permissions, things worked smoothly. But I need to do queries like the ones below, located in `fb-stats.php`. I guess the way I have the params is wrong, but I don't exactly know the right way to format it.

Here's `fb.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

    // Checks if token is set and redirects to another page.
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        // Logged in!

        header('Location: fb-stats.php'); exit();
    }

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'MYAPPID',
        'app_secret' => 'MYAPPSECRET',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    // The site below is 'example' is actually my live site.
    $params = array(
            'scope' => 'ads_management',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/login-callback.php',
        );

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($params);

    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
?>
```

Here's `login-callback.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'MYAPPID',
        'app_secret' => 'MYAPPSECRET',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);


    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
        if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
            try {
                $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
            }
            catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
                exit;
            }
        }

        header('Location: fb-stats.php'); exit();
    }
```

Here's `fb-stats.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'MYAPPID',
        'app_secret' => 'MYAPPSECRET',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken('access-token');

    try {
        $response = $fb->get('/PAGEID/insights/page_impressions?period=day', '{access token}');
        $insightsNode = $response->getGraphEdge();
    }
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    var_dump($insightsNode);
```

The query I'm trying to execute needs permissions of `ads_management` and `read_insights` but I'm confused as to how to get mutltiple scopes going aside from the error I'm currently getting for the `redirect_uri` not being absolute. How would I go about fixing these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$params = array(
       'scope' => 'ads_management',
       'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/login-callback.php',
    );
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($params);
```

The getLoginUrl method expects *two* parameters - but you are passing only one array to it here.

The correct way to use this method is

```
$helper->getLoginUrl('http://example.com/login-callback.php', ['ads_management']);
```

The redirect URI is passed as the first parameter (string value), and then the second parameter is the scope (array of permissions you want to ask for.)

(Whether you want to put those values into a different array for configuration purposes beforehand, is up to you.)